# Icons don't display in polymer 2

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use components like paper-rating, font awesome icons but they don't display anything in the page. I see that the tag is recoginsed but nothing is visible on the page.  Below is a sample use of star-rating. Nethier the rating nor the map icon work

```
      <section>
            <template is="dom-if" if={{tests}}>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items={{tests}}>
                    <a my-data="test" href="assessment/{{item.testId}}">
                        <paper-card  class ="header"  heading="{{item.assessmentTopic}}" image=""elevation="1" animated-shadow="false">
                                <iron-icon icon="maps:directions-bus"></iron-icon>
                            <div class="card-content" id="{{item.testId}}">
                                <img style="width : 75px; margin : 2px;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-blackboard-inscribed-with-scientific-formulas-and-calculations-in-physics-and-mathematics-538136431.jpg" />
                                <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 10;">
                                    <div class="small">
                                        {{item.createdBy}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="small">
                                        {{item.testId}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                            <star-rating rating="4"></star-rating>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </paper-card>
                    </a>
                </template>
            </template>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to solve this by updating iron-meta to version 2.0.0 in the bower.json and running bower update.